# why put dozens of * before function pointer or function that return a function pointer compliles?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have found that this code dealing with multiple function pointer dereferences unexpectedly compiles, despite seeming not to be valid. How can this compile? Is it a bug in the compiler? I am using gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
int addInt(int n,int m)      // function
{
    return n+m;
}

int (*(*functionFactoryPtr)(int n))(int, int); // pointer

int (*(functionFactory)(int n))(int, int)   // function
{
    std::cout << "Got parameter" <<  n << std::endl;
    int (*functionPtr)(int,int) = &addInt;
    return functionPtr;
}

int main()
{
    // functionFactoryPtr = @functionFactory;
    std::cout << (******(*****functionFactory)(4))(3,6) << std::endl;  // How is this not an error?

}
```

Comment: decay mayhap: a reference to functions decays to a function pointer at the drop of a hat.  `*` returns a reference: next `*` decays reference to function then dereferences it?  etc.

Comment: Well.. it crashes in C. It's just valid in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function lvalue is implicitly convertible to a pointer to the function ([conv.func]). In your example, the function is converted to a pointer before each dereference.