# Example why someone should use triple-pointers in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

I'm searching for an example or explanation why someone should (or should not) use triple-pointers in C/C++.

Are there any examples where triple-pointer arise?

I am especially looking for source-code which uses triple-pointers.

Comment: That's how you become a [*three star programmer*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: I do not want to be "three star programmer" at all ;)

Comment: I'm tempted to post "when you don't understand the concept of abstraction." as an answer, but I guess for now I won't.

Comment: I'd like to see example code of what a triple pointer is.

Comment: `void MakeJagged( int*** arr, int width, int height );`

Comment: When you want to write a function that modifies a `**`. In C, without reference, you need one more layer of pointer.

Comment: A better question would be: *an example of why one should NOT use triple-pointers*...

Comment: Maybe you should pick one language. I can't think of a situation where you'd need a triple pointer in C++.

Comment: @fabio same list, really, bit with implementation and use cases added.

Comment: @aGer _"Edit: Especially i'm looking for a source-code which uses triple-pointers."_ THX for pointing out why this question is off-topic.

Comment: Asking for lists and suggestions is frowned upon. Pointers to pointers to pointers is pretty uncommon. Other than a three dimensional array, I've only seen it used legitimately once or twice, and those probably could have been avoided. The rest look like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387128/why-put-dozens-of-before-function-pointer-or-function-that-return-a-function-p

Comment: aGer: There's nothing particularly scary or magic about multiple indirection.  Triple indirection is relatively rare, but there are use cases for it (R's is one of the better ones).  Instead of saying "I don't want to be a three star programmer", take the time to learn *why* such constructs may exist.  Sometimes you have to work with high-dimension data.  Sometimes you have multiple layers of indirection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best example that comes to mind is a sparse multi-level table. For instance one way to implement properties for Unicode characters might be:

```
prop_type ***proptable;
...
prop_type prop = proptable[c>>14][c>>7&0x7f][c&0x7f];
```

In this case `proptable` would need to have a triple-pointer type (and possibly quadruple pointer if the final resulting type is a pointer type). The reason for doing this as multiple levels rather than one flat table is that, at the first and second levels, multiple entries can point to the same subtable when the contents are all the same (e.g. huge CJK ranges).

Here's another example of a multi-level table that I implemented; I can't say I'm terribly proud of the design but given the constraints the code has to satisfy, it's one of the least-bad implementation choices:

http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/aio/aio.c?id=56fbaa3bbe73f12af2bfbbcf2adb196e6f9fe264

Comment: That isn't a triple pointer. That's just a 3d array. You would only need triple pointers for a jagged 3d array.

Comment: @VoidStar: No, using a 3d array defeats the whole purpose and makes it equivalent to a flat array. The key word is **sparse**. I updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: If it were a 3d array, it would necessarily use a total of `68*128*128*sizeof ***proptable` bytes of storage, which is huge. In practice such multi-level tables fit in several kb.

Comment: In fairness to @VoidStar, my answer was less clear when the first comment was posted.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to return an array of pointers to variable length strings via a function parameter:

```
int array_of_strings(int *num_strings, char ***string_data)
{
    int n = 32;
    char **pointers = malloc(n * sizeof(*pointers));
    if (pointers == 0)
        return -1;  // Failure
    char line[256];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n && fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0; i++)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(line);
        if (line[len-1] == '\n')
            line[len-1] = '\0';
        pointers[i] = strdup(line);
        if (pointers[i] == 0)
        {
            // Release already allocated resources
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                free(pointers[j]);
            free(pointers);
            return -1;  // Failure
        }
    }
    *num_strings = i;
    *string_data = pointers;
    return 0;  // Success
}
```

<sup>*Compiled code.*</sup>

Comment: Note that the for loop for freeing pointers and the array of pointers should be extracted into a separate function and used both in the clean-up path for error handling and in the calling function when finished with the array of strings.  You pass the number of initialized pointers (`i` in the error recovery code) and the pointers (variable `pointers` in the code) to the function.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a linked list you have to store the address of the first element of the list `( first pointer )` .

If you need to change in that list you need another pointer `( two pointer)`

If you need to pass your list that you are changing in two pointers and change it in another function you need another pointer  `( three pointer )`...

They are a lots of examples

Answer (score 2):

I've used triple pointers in C++:

There is an interface written for a Java program:

https://github.com/BenLand100/SMART/blob/master/src/SMARTPlugin.h

and it takes an array of strings.

```
typedef void (*_SMARTPluginInit)(SMARTInfo *ptr, bool *replace, int *buttonc, char ***buttonv, int **buttonid, _SMARTButtonPressed *buttonproc);
```

Then in my program I do:

```
char* btnTexts[2] = {"Disable OpenGL_Enable OpenGL", "Enable Debug_Disable glDebug"}; //array of C-style strings.

void SMARTPluginInit(SMARTInfo* ptr, bool* ReplaceButtons, int* ButtonCount, char*** ButtonTexts, int** ButtonIDs, _SMARTButtonPressed* ButtonCallback)
{
    *ButtonText = btnTexts; //return an array of strings.
}
```

but in C++, you can use a reference instead of pointer and it'd become:

```
void SMARTPluginInit(SMARTInfo* ptr, bool* ReplaceButtons, int* ButtonCount, char** &ButtonTexts, int** ButtonIDs, _SMARTButtonPressed* ButtonCallback)
{
    ButtonText = btnTexts; //return an array of strings.
}
```

Notice now that "ButtonTexts" is a reference to an array of C-style strings now.

A `char***` can be a pointer to an array of C-style strings and that's one time that you'd use it.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example is a pointer to an array of arrays of arrays.

Answer (score -3):

Triple pointer is a pointer variable that points to a pointer which in turn points to another pointer. The use of this complex programming technique is that usually in which companies process tons and tons of data at one time .A single pointer would point to a single block of data (suppose in a large file) using the triple pointer would result in 3 times faster processing as different blocks of data(in the same file) can be pointed by different pointer and thus data could be accessed/processed faster (unlike 1 pointer going through the whole file).